# The "smart" way to crawl the web

Tags: python, database, web-crawler, bots

I have a project in which I have to crawl the web for `lyrics`, I am implementing `depth-first search` and I am making a database in a list (which contains nested lists which will later be saved in a file). My idea is to get the HTML content of the website and save it in the file, and then parse out the lyrics from it. But the problem is that it's very slow and I am unnecessary pages(ad links) Is there any solution or a "better" was to implement the bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give specific recommendations we'd have to see your code. However, HTML parsing is a very difficult problem; be sure to use an existing parsing library and don't attempt to create your own.

In general it is better to implement web-crawlers using breadth-first search and not depth-first. Depth-first searches often make many calls to the same domain and path; this can be detected by web sites and your crawler may be throttled or even blocked. Breadth-first crawlers avoid this and have more opportunities for optimizations; for example recognizing that two sites are copies of each other, and abandoning the slower site.

Answer (score 0):

Lyrics are often TXT, whereas ads are not, so you could restrict search to text. The negative aspect of that is that you'd certainly miss some HTML lyrics.